# Android Studio 4.0.1 Drops connected device

Tags: android-studio, adb

[image]I'm running Android Studio 4.0.1 and when I take a break The connected Devices drop down clears out even though my Android Phone is still connected.  Any ideas why?

I have to unplug the device, reconnect and then wait a few seconds before Android Studio agrees the device is available and I can push code to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "when I take a break?" how long? is your PC going into standby mode?

Comment: Thanks Lino  the PC sometimes goes into standby mode, but more often around 3 - 4 hours. I stop Android development and doe something else perhaps some iOS development.